# SFTP - Limitar usuários

Tags: linux, sftp

Estou testando um servidor SFTP. Na minha configuração do sftp, consta a linha "Match Group sftponly". Ou seja, pelo que entendi somente os usuários que são do grupo 'sftponly' poderiam acessar o SFTP. 
Porém notei algo preocupante. No mesmo servidor tenho um usuário de nome 'john', criado pra acessar outro serviço. Ou seja, ele não é do grupo 'sftponly'. 
Mas se o john abre o Filezilla e tenta acessar o SFTP, ele consegue, mesmo não sendo do grupo 'sftponly'. 
E pior! Notei que, no Filezilla ele tem acesso (mesmo que somente leitura) ao sistema todo! Por ele não ser do grupo 'sftponly', ele não é direcionado para a pasta determinada no parâmetro ChrootDirectory do sftp. Ele simplesmente cai na sua pasta HOME e de lá pode sair dela e ver todas as demais pastas do sistema.
Minha pergunta: é possível limitar o SFTP somente aos usuários que realmente façam parte do grupo 'sftponly', mas permitir que john continue acessando outros serviços que utilizem o protocolo SSH?

Comment: Qual servidor sftp esta usando? Por acaso é o `vsftpd`?

Comment: dei uma olhada na doc e pelo que entendi o parametro MatchGroup na verdade serve para criar usuários sem shell(SSH) e não o inverso (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot), vc pode usar jails para isso -> https://linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver:

1- Todos os usuários Git deverão estar no grupo 'git'.

2- Em /etc/passwd, deixe o prompt padrão do usuário git como /bin/bash mesmo, ao invés do /usr/bin/git-shell.

3- No arquivo /etc/ssh/sshd_config, logo abaixo das configurações já existentes do SFTP, crie uma nova sessão,
que captará todo o fluxo do grupo git:

```
Match Group git 
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Feito isso, o usuário só conseguirá acesso ao seu repositório Git, mas não terá mais acesso ao shell SSH, SFTP, SCP ou qualquer outro serviço do SSH.